# Facing issue with Copy-Item in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy folders using `Copy-Item` cmdlet in PowerShell. I am getting the error

> Copy-Item : An item with the specified name already exists "CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists:

How to resolve this issue, because I have to copy both the files?

```cs
$var1 = Copy-Item "D:\GRACE\boo\" -Destination "D:\GRACE_CORE\foo"
$var2 = Copy-Item "D:\GRACE" -Destination "D:\GRACE_CORE\foo"
```

Comment: thanks @dahston for quick reply , but i need to declare 2 variables , Is there a command which is alternate to Copy-Item which does same functionality

Comment: Why not just use Windwos RoboCopy for this effort. If you really want to script, you can use robocopy with it. Just search for PowerShell using robocopy.

Comment: What do you mean you "need to declare 2 variables"? `Copy-Item` does not return any output by default, so both variables would be empty anyway.